# can not show event on fullcalender dynamically in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show a calendar event on fullcalendar dynamically. I've tried the code given below but it did not succeed:

```
@model List<EcommerceDbFirstApproch.Models.EventMaster>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DashBoard";
    var event_data = @Model;
}

<style type="text/css">
    .mycalhedar {
        background: #000;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .mycalhedar h1 {
            color: #fff;
    }
</style>

<br />
<script src="~/Content/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/themes/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div data-role="page" id="index">

    <div class="mycalhedar">
        <h1>My Team</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id='calendar' style="width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

</div>
<!-- /page -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function (e, data) {
        debugger;
        var myary = [];
        @foreach (var h in Model)
        {
            @:alert("@h.EventTitle");
            @:alert("@h.StartDate");
            @:alert("@h.EndDate");
        }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
             ContentType: "application/json",
            editable: true,

            events: [{
                    @foreach (var h in Model)
                    {
                        title: @h.EventTitle.ToString();
                       start: @h.StartDate.ToString();
                       end: @h.EndDate.ToString();                                                
                    }
            }]

            });      
    });
</script>
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I want to show the events dynamically on the fullcalender demo. Thanks

Comment: try this `events:@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`

Comment: I suppose you have javascript errors in your page. Please provide "apex" for title, start and end (ex. title: '@h.EventTitle.ToString()').